# How can a iframe embed an https 403 forbidden site in it?

Tags: html, web, iframe, http-status-code-403, clickjacking

I found a website which is able access forbidden sites in it's iframe, so I inspected the webpage and the iframe and found out that there were not much of scripting or designing but a simple iframe that was showing a frobidden site into it. I find out that the site is forbidden by copying the src of the iframe and try to access it with different browsers like chrome, Firefox, Tor with no success. Can anyone explain it to me how does that website was able to access unauthorized content in it's iframe? 
Note: that website has a .se (Sweden) top level domain

Comment: You can get better answers if you provide with more details - now it only allows for guessing. A question like this is not likely to be answered exhaustively, because there could be number of ways of the remote machine deciding to respond with 403.

Comment: ...that said, I would *guess* that the server will make its decision based on headers that the browser sends alongside with the request. Examine the headers in e.g. Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you can't access that site is `.htaccess` file.
This file exist at server.
And here, server manager can set the permission to access.
So you couldn't access that url via iframe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Can you explain it in detail?