# electron: google 403 We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron

I'm developing an electron application. When I load the google login page using iframe, I get an error: '403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know.'

How can I skip this error and get the google login page?

Q: Why not use an electron window to load the google login page?

A: It's true that using an electron window to load the google login page doesn't have any errors! But electron window will consume more memory!

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

> Display external web content in an isolated frame and process.
>
> Process: Renderer This class is not exported from the 'electron'
> module. It is only available as a return value of other methods in the
> Electron API.
>
> Use the webview tag to embed 'guest' content (such as web pages) in
> your Electron app. The guest content is contained within the webview
> container. An embedded page within your app controls how the guest
> content is laid out and rendered.
>
> Unlike an iframe, the webview runs in a separate process than your
> app. It doesn't have the same permissions as your web page and all
> interactions between your app and embedded content will be
> asynchronous. This keeps your app safe from embedded content.
> Note: Most methods called on the webview from the host page require a
> synchronous call to the main process.

[Reference](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag)

if you are using ***iframe*** for google sign you will get a content security policy (CSP) error
A result like this

[image]

```
<iframe style="display: flex ;height: 1000px" width="100%" height="100%"
        src="https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fu%2F0%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fu%2F0%2F&emr=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"></iframe>
```

**Solution**:

Electron already introduced a webview tag

So The result may like this

[image]

```
    <webview style="
height: 500px;display: flex"  src="https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fu%2F0%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fu%2F0%2F&emr=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"  ></webview>
```

**NB:**

You must add the `webPreferences` property in `Browserwindow` and the webview tag must be true otherwise the view tag will be hidden. The default webview tag is false .like this

[image]

So you must add like this

```
 function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, webPreferences: {webviewTag: true}})
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))
}
```

Comment: thanks for your tip! :) 
I checked the internet but I don't know why there is a 403 error, please excuse me I am a chrome newbie and would like to know why 403?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53475551/7706354